# How to create multiple Repository in OpenCMIS?

Tags: cmis, opencmis

I am working on java integrated with CMIS Repository.And i tried with all functions in OpenCMIS Fileshare by making changes in repository.properties as per our Requirement.

Here i want to create multiple repository, now i configured creating multiple repository in **repository.properties** file **/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/repository.properties**.

```
repository.secondRepository = {user.home}
repository.secondRepository.readwrite = test, cmisuser  
repository.secondRepository.readonly = reader,user
```

Is there any REST api or other way to create multiple repository.

Comment: What server product are you using? Some product do not even allow creating repositories.

Comment: camunda server, and now i am able  to create repositories by using addRepository() in cmis fileshare.

Comment: Camunda is a CMIS *client*. I guess you are using it with a CMIS *server*?

Answer (score 3):

Repository management is not in the scope of CMIS and therefore there is no standardized API for adding repositories.

But the OpenCMIS FileShare implementation can dynamically add new repositories. The class `FileShareRepositoryManager` provides the method `addRepository()` to do this.